# Know of any iOS/OS X Photo Frameworks

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im working on an iPhone app and would like to add a photo element to it. The features Im looking for are:

- A photo gallery in my app.
- Take a photo from my app and return one or more images to the app gallery.
- Upload images to a server.
- Image resizing.

I know there are a lot of great frameworks out there for iOS/OS X so I was hoping someone knew of one that could accomplish the above.

Also I was wondering if it would be a better idea to have a framework for the photography features and a fuller networking framework for uploads and downloads? Im leaning towards two because Im familiar with MKNetworkKit : https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit

---

I just thought of another thing. I need to set up a server with an API so I can send and receive photos and data. Does anyone know of any frameworks/libraries/toolkits that would help me set up the server for uploading/downloading photos and data?

I dont want to program from scratch what I dont have to. Why reinvent the wheel when I can give it chrome plating and spinners :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) for generating gallery views before, but it's not been updated for a little while, and it doesn't cover everything you want out of the box. You'll probably be best served by splitting it into multiple libraries to cover the necessary functionality, and adapting them as needed.

In terms of the backend server you'd probably get quite far with Rails and the Paperclip gem. I set up a basic image and data serving API in about half a day with the two, and there's a fair amount of tutorials showing how to do it with the Rails scaffolding commands. To get you started [a video of how to build a RESTful API in Rails](http://gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/21-building-a-restful-api-in-rails-3) and [a railscast on Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip).

Comment: Thanks! Im going to really look into MWPhotoBrowser. As for Rails thats one of the few languages I'm not familiar with. I guess really should be though. I know .Net, PHP, Python, C#, Java & JS. I really didn't want to work with .Net, Java or C# because I dont have a dev environment readily available. That leaves me with Python (which I've never used for web dev) and PHP wich is probably a poor choice for the job. Thanks for the realization.

Comment: I'd say use what you know, but I'm not familiar enough with PHP or Python to know if it has a `rails generate scaffold` equivalent command to just get the boiler plate done and dusted. However, if you're familiar with those then picking up RoR should be pretty straightforward.